# How to resize my video source and align in row

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Now my video align down and too big size and over the body. Videos don't resize when I scale the screen also. I need my video align in row and resize like attached pictures.

[Now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4aZd0.png)
[I want like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lT4mE.png)

Here is my code :

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.content{
  max-width: auto;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0 30px;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
}
.gallery {
    display: grid;
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
      <div class="gallery">
              <video controls>
                <source src="/video/vertical.mp4" type="video/mp4" >
              </video>
              <video controls>
                <source src="/video/square.mp4" type="video/mp4">
              </video>
              <video controls>
                <source src="/video/normal.mp4" type="video/mp4">
              </video>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.gallery {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    gap: 10px;
    width: 100%;
}

video {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <video controls>
    <source src="/video/vertical.mp4" type="video/mp4" >
  </video>
  <video controls>
    <source src="/video/square.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
  <video controls>
    <source src="/video/normal.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Magic is it the flex & no wrap

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        body{
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        header{
            text-transform: uppercase;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .wrapper{
            max-width: 960px;
            width: 100%;
            margin: 20px auto;
        }
        .columns{
            display: flex;
            flex-flow: nowrap;
            justify-content: center;
            margin: 5px 0;
        }
        .video{
            flex: 2;
            margin: 5px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="warpper">
        <header>
            <h3>Content Column</h3>
        </header>
        <section class="columns">
            <video controls class="video">
              <source src="/video/vertical.mp4" type="video/mp4" >
            </video>

            <video controls class="video">
              <source src="/video/square.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>

            <video controls class="video">
              <source src="/video/normal.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
        </section>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```